# Cypress logs out when using cy.visit()

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, authorization, cypress

I'm sending multiple API requests and everything works fine, until I try to navigate to the page that was generated during API testing. When I navigate to the page using cy.visit() function I get unauthorized and all subsequent requests are being sent without authorization token, even though I added authorization header to the `cy.visit()` function.

Any help would be appreciated

```
    var accessToken
    before(function () {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://someurl.com/connect/token',
            form: true,
            body: {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: 'admin',
                password: 'pass',
                client_id: 'client_id',
                client_secret: 'secret'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            accessToken = response.body.access_token
        })
    })
   
   //api requests

    it('Navigates to order page', () => {
        cy.visit(`https://someurl.com/orders/${orderId}`, { auth: { bearer: accessToken.replace('Bearer ', '') } })
    })
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by changing authorization from backed api request to frontend login form and then whitelisting local storage.

I had to add this piece of code

```
        Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
            if (keys) {
                return
            }
        }
```

And now my spec file looks like this:

```
    before(function () {
        cy.server()
        cy.route('GET', '/api/orders/orders?PageNo=1&Size=20').as('orders')

        cy.LogIn('email', 'pass')
    
        //wrapping access token from the request after successfull authorization

        cy.wait('@orders').then((request) => {
            cy.wrap(request.requestHeaders.Authorization).as('accessToken')
        })
        
        //whitelisting local storage

        Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
            if (keys) {
                return
            }
        }
    })

    it('A',()=>{
      cy.visit('some url') //it works!
    })
```

Also when restarting the test I was still logged in. To prevent this from happening I added clearing local storage at the very beginning of before() function

```
        window.localStorage.clear()
```

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/461

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like the antipattern example in the [Cypress Docs: Core Concepts: Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases) example.  Using [as](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html#Syntax) to create an alias, you could do something like:

```
before(function () {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://someurl.com/connect/token',
        form: true,
        body: {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'pass',
            client_id: 'client_id',
            client_secret: 'secret'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        cy.wrap(response.body.access_token).as('accessToken')
    })
})

//api requests

it('Navigates to order page', function() {
  const accessToken = this.accessToken
  cy.visit({
    url: `https://someurl.com/orders/${orderId}`,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': accessToken
    }
  })
})
```

**NOTE**: It is necessary to change the closure of the `it()` block from an arrow function to a regular function because the arrow function uses the lexical scope `this`, and will not include the alias created in the `before()` closure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, that I was using antipattern, but using aliases still doesn't fix my issue. Cypress still logs me out when navigating to the page.

Comment: Nope, its just like on screenshots above

Comment: I updated the answer with one finding.  They added the ability for `cy.visit()` to send headers and I believe this will work for your use case: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/3489/files

Comment: @DanielBank In this case just had to change one line a little bit `'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}``. But anyway, the result is still the same. I guess I would need to come up with some other solution

Comment: Previously you were stripping `Bearer ` from `accessToken`.  If you do `Bearer ${accessToken}`, would that not be `Bearer Bearer ...`?  Can you add a `cy.wrap(accessToken).debug()` and share what it is set as?

Comment: @DanielBank I`ll post only beginning, because token is too long ```Current Subject:  eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZBRTA4NUYxNkE4MEQ2NURDMjREMDFDNkUzQTc2MTA2NzQwMERE```

Comment: I think you need to replace `Current Subject` with `Bearer`.  The header should look like `Authorization: Bearer <token>`