# Cypress : login with Bearer token

Tags: authentication, token, cypress

Recently I wanted to login with an access token (I have the API command to generate it), but I certainly missunderstood something. I did what it was done in this subject (the question proposition) : [Cypress logs out when using cy.visit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251334/cypress-logs-out-when-using-cy-visit)

But I didn't understand the final answer of Vladimir Krygin, plus, I don't know what is his cy.LogIn() function.

If someone can help me to understand his answer ! Or Vladimir Krygin himself !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `cy.Login()` is their custom command which is presumably the  `cy.request()` and more steps from the `before()` in the question.